# How to kill a function which starts a process using Subprocess.Popen and move to next line of code?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess

I am a newbie and automating few test cases in linux. I want to go to next line after subprocess.Popen and print - "I am executing".

`subprocess.Popen(['./xyzScript.sh']).communicate()
print("I am executing")`

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`communicate` is a blocking operation. It is for getting the content of the process' `stdout` and `stderr`. Since you discarded its return value, it appears that you have no need of it. Simply running:

```
subprocess.Popen(['./xyzScript.sh'])
print("I am executing")
```

is enough.

By default, the `stdout` and `stderr` is not redirected, i.e., they go to where the `stdout` and `stderr` of your calling python script is. If you wish to interact with the output of your shell script programmically, you should configure the stdout and stderr flag of `Popen`. For example, if you wish to discard the output of your shell script all together, run:

```
subprocess.Popen(['./xyzScript.sh'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, )
print("I am executing")
```